# Continuous version of uniform continuity?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, uniform-convergence

Studying Fourier analysis, I faced this problem which author skipped saying "clearly".
$$G_\delta(x)=e^{-\pi \delta x^2}$$ Let $f\in S(\mathbb R)$(Schwartz Space).
Then $$\int_\infty ^\infty \hat{f}(\xi)G_\delta(\xi)d\xi \to \int_\infty ^\infty \hat{f}(\xi)d\xi $$
I guess this problem has something to do with uniform convergence(which is about the interchange of order of integral and limit). Is there a continuous version of uniform convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the limit is taken as $\delta\to 0$. In this case, since $G_{\delta}\to 0$ pointwise, and $|G_{\delta}(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)|\leq |\hat{f}(\xi)|\in L^1$ due to the fact that $\hat{f}$ is Schwartz, the dominated convergence theorem implies the convergence of the integrals.

Comment: I have not studied measure theory and am using stein's Fourier analysis book. Is there a way to solve this using basic analysis?

Comment: You could try proving from the definition that the integrands converge uniformly. However, the $G_{\delta}$ don’t converge uniformly, since in order for $1-e^{-\pi \delta x^2} < \epsilon$, you’d need $\delta < -\ln(1-\epsilon)/(\pi x^2)$, which can’t be made uniform in $x$. If $\hat{f}$ were compactly supported, then you could probably conclude uniform convergence, but you’d likely need to do more work if it’s not.

Comment: Thanks. I thought $G_\delta$ converges uniformly but it doesn't. I solved it by separating the interval [-N, N] and the rest such that the differences of the integrals are smaller than $\epsilon/2$ for each interval. Then $G_\delta$ uniformly converges in the closed interval.